# Configure script cannot find stdlib.h or sys/types.h

Tags: configuration, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04, std

Earlier I ran into [an issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335527/kernel-panic-after-attempting-to-install-glibc) with Ubuntu on my machine.  I have since fixed the issue.  Currently I am trying to configure the latest stable version of MPICH ([MPICH 3.0.4](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/)).  However, it seems to fail when attempting to determine the size of basic datatypes.

```
checking size of char... 0
checking size of unsigned char... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of unsigned short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of unsigned int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking size of unsigned long... 0
checking size of long long... 0
checking size of unsigned long long... 0
checking size of float... 0
checking size of double... 0
checking size of long double... 0
checking size of void *... 0
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) no
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking size of wchar_t... 0
checking size of float_int... 0
checking size of double_int... 0
checking size of long_int... 0
checking size of short_int... 0
checking size of two_int... 0
checking size of long_double_int... 0
checking sys/bitypes.h usability... no
checking sys/bitypes.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: sys/bitypes.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sys/bitypes.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sys/bitypes.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sys/bitypes.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sys/bitypes.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ---------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to mpich-discuss@mcs.anl.gov ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ---------------------------------------- ##
```

After looking through the `config.log` file, as suggested, I have found that the configure script cannot find `sys/types.h` or `stdlib.h`.

```
...
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
...
```

Yet, I have found them both: `/usr/include/stdlib.h` and 
`/usr/include/sys/types.h`.  What could cause the configure script to not find these two system libraries?

Comment: `configure` creates a log file called `config.log` where it logs the source code of every small test C program, the possible compiler errors and the result of each program's invocation. Have a look at it for more clues.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have edited my original post.  It turns out the configure script is not finding the `stdlib.h` or `sys/types.h`.  Any thoughts why?

Comment: In Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 the `sys` directory is moved to an architecture-specific location, e.g. `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys` and one has to explicitly add `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` to the preprocessor options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With time not on my side, I decided to perform a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.  After doing so, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error when building on an RHEL5 box.  It appears to be due to a failure to find `libtorque.so.2`, which is installed in `/usr/local/lib` on this system (which is not automatically searched for libraries).  The clue was hidden in `src/pm/hydra/config.log`:

```
configure:15881: checking size of unsigned int
configure:15886: gcc -o conftest    -O2    -I/home/price/Software/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl/include -I/home/price/Software/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl/include -I/home/price/Software/mpich-3.0.4/src/openpa/src -I/home/price/Software/mpich-3.0.4/src/openpa/src -I/home/price/Software/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpi/romio/include  -lnsl conftest.c -ltorque  >&5
configure:15886: $? = 0
configure:15886: ./conftest
./conftest: error while loading shared libraries: libtorque.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The solution was to put `/usr/local/lib` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.